# CloudFront multi origin and cache behaviour issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have defined 2 S3 buckets as origins in CF.

```
Origin 1 : mybucket1.amazonaws.com
Origin 2 : mybucket2.amazonaws.com/images
```

I only want to distribute images folder in mybucket2.

I created a cache behaviour with the path pattern `/images` pointing to `Origin2`

I've tried to access the images using the url
`https://lksngfd4w24.cloudfront.net/images/image1.jpg`

Seems like CF is appending the cache behaviour path pattern to the s3 path. Above url throws an error like below.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>
images/images/image1.jpg
</Key>
<RequestId>sdanfladnfaf</RequestId>
<HostId>
   medlakfmkamfldaf
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is there a way to stop CF appending the path prefix to the S3 URL?. Or is there any other way to achieve this kind of requirement using a single distribution but with multiple origins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, add the both origins with base path and configure the behaviors such that

- Default behavior for /* is Origin 1
- Behavior /images/* overrides to
  Origin 2

Note: In your Origin 2 it requires to have images folder for this to work which is a limitation with CloudFront behavior mappings to S3 origins.

If you need further extensions you can do it using, Edge Lambda by changing the request URLs to different paths in origin.

Comment: That's a way of achieving it. My concern is that CF will keep trying to distribute the whole content of the bucket2, I've enforced a bucket policy to allow CF to access only the images folder to avoid it. Hope Amazon will improve CF - S3 integration with much flexibility. I'd skip Lambda to save the simplicity of the design and the vendor locking.Solution is sub-optimal but works. Thanks  and appreciate it very much.